# Is there any way to access nested or re-raised exceptions in python?

Tags: python, traceback

A common pattern in python is to catch an error in an upstream module and re-raise that error as something more useful.

```
try:
    config_file = open('config.ini', 'r')
except IOError:
    raise ConfigError('Give me my config, user!')
```

This will generate a stack trace of the form

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
__main__.ConfigError: Give me my config, user!
```

Is there any way to access the wrapped exception in order to generate a stack trace more like this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
__builtin__.IOError: File Does not exist.
Exception wrapped by:
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
__main__.ConfigError: Give me my config, user!
```

## EDIT:

The problem i'm trying to defeat is that some 3rd party code can wrap exceptions up to 3 times and I want to be able to determine the root cause, i.e. a generic way to inspect the exception stack and determine the root cause of an exception without having to add any extra code to 3rd party modules.

Comment: does sys.last_traceback help at all?

Comment: also maybe check out the [python traceback module](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html?highlight=traceback)

Comment: Sorry, this is one of those annoying questions, but... why?

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to do this without explicitly going to the exception block? I can print an exception message one at a time... but is there a better way?

Comment: @senderle "some 3rd party code can wrap exceptions up to 3 times and I want to be able to determine the root cause"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is known as *Exception Chaining* and is suported in Python 3.

PEP 3134: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/

In Python 2, the old exception is lost when you raise a new one, unless you save it in the `except` block.

Comment: What do you mean by "save it in the except block"? Is there a standard way for doing that?

Comment: There was no standard way to do that back in Python 2.x. (I know this is a very old thread but I wanted to make sure newcomers understand this)

Answer (score 4):

Use the `traceback` [module](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html). It will allow you to access the most recent traceback and store it in a string. For example,

```
import traceback
try:
    config_file = open('config.ini', 'r')
except OSError:
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    raise ConfigError('Give me my config, user!',tb)
```

The "nested" traceback will be stored in tb and passed to ConfigError, where you can work with it however you want.

Comment: Also, the result of format_exc() (that is stored in tb) is just a string, which consists of exactly the same text that would be printed out if it were not in a try/except block.

Comment: To answer your edit, as far as I know, the format_exc function will output all available information in the traceback. If a 3rd party module "suppresses" some information in a try/except loop, you won't be able to retrieve it without modifying that *particular* try/except loop.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of how to unwind [PEP-3134](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) exception chains.

Note that due to legacy reasons some Python frameworks may not use exception chaining, but instead of wrap exceptions in their own way. For example. [SQLALchemy DBABIError uses `orig` attribute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError).

```py
class Foobar(Exception):
    pass


class Dummy(Exception):
    pass


def func1():
    raise Foobar("func1() argh")


def func2():
    try:
        func1()
    except Exception as e:
        raise Dummy("func2 vyaaarrg!") from e

try:
    func2()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Current {e.__class__}: {e}")
    print(f"Nested {e.__cause__.__class__}:{e.__cause__}")
```

Prints

```
Current <class '__main__.Dummy'>: func2 vyaaarrg!
Nested <class '__main__.Foobar'>:func1() argh
```